# How can I run grocery with sql server?

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I have grocery crud with codeigniter running in xampp with php 5.6.8.

I made codeigniter connect with sqlsrv but when i open the crud i receive:

```
Error Number: 42000/156

[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

SHOW COLUMNS FROM `PERSONA_TEST`

Filename: D:/Trabajo/xampp/htdocs/creditos/crud/application/models/grocery_crud_model.php

Line Number: 431
```

What i know:

I have a sql statement that's not made to work with sqlserver sintax. Should I need to edit grocery_crud_model?

Thanks!

Comment: As i see grocery only supports mysql: http://www.grocerycrud.com/forums/topic/1286-connecting-to-sql-server-database/

Comment: I will need to modify the grocery_crud_model.php. https://github.com/scoumbourdis/grocery-crud/issues/168

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of time i made to use sqlsrv. I edited the grocery_crud_model.php

```
<?php
/**
 * PHP grocery CRUD
 *
 * LICENSE
 *
 * Grocery CRUD is released with dual licensing, using the GPL v3 (license-gpl3.txt) and the MIT license (license-mit.txt).
 * You don't have to do anything special to choose one license or the other and you don't have to notify anyone which license you are using.
 * Please see the corresponding license file for details of these licenses.
 * You are free to use, modify and distribute this software, but all copyright information must remain.
 *
 * @package     grocery CRUD
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2010 through 2012, John Skoumbourdis
 * @license     https://github.com/scoumbourdis/grocery-crud/blob/master/license-grocery-crud.txt
 * @version     1.4.2
 * @author      John Skoumbourdis <scoumbourdisj@gmail.com>
 */

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Grocery CRUD Model
 *
 *
 * @package     grocery CRUD
 * @author      John Skoumbourdis <scoumbourdisj@gmail.com>
 * @version     1.2
 * @link        http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation
 */
class grocery_CRUD_Model  extends CI_Model  {

    protected $primary_key = null;
    protected $table_name = null;
    protected $relation = array();
    protected $relation_n_n = array();
    protected $primary_keys = array();

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function db_table_exists($table_name = null)
    {
        return $this->db->table_exists($table_name);
    }

    function get_list()
    {
        if($this->table_name === null)
            return false;

        $select = "{$this->table_name}.*";

        //set_relation special queries
        if(!empty($this->relation))
        {
            foreach($this->relation as $relation)
            {
                list($field_name , $related_table , $related_field_title) = $relation;
                $unique_join_name = $this->_unique_join_name($field_name);
                $unique_field_name = $this->_unique_field_name($field_name);

                if(strstr($related_field_title,'{'))
                {
                    $related_field_title = str_replace(" ","&nbsp;",$related_field_title);
                    $select .= ", CONCAT('".str_replace(array('{','}'),array("',COALESCE({$unique_join_name}.",", ''),'"),str_replace("'","\\'",$related_field_title))."') as $unique_field_name";
                }
                else
                {
                    $select .= ", $unique_join_name.$related_field_title AS $unique_field_name";
                }

                if($this->field_exists($related_field_title))
                    $select .= ", `{$this->table_name}`.$related_field_title AS '{$this->table_name}.$related_field_title'";
            }
        }

        //set_relation_n_n special queries. We prefer sub queries from a simple join for the relation_n_n as it is faster and more stable on big tables.
        if(!empty($this->relation_n_n))
        {
            $select = $this->relation_n_n_queries($select);
        }

        $this->db->select($select, false);

        $results = $this->db->get($this->table_name)->result();

        return $results;
    }

    public function get_row($table_name = null)
    {
        $table_name = $table_name === null ? $this->table_name : $table_name;

        return $this->db->get($table_name)->row();
    }

    public function set_primary_key($field_name, $table_name = null)
    {
        $table_name = $table_name === null ? $this->table_name : $table_name;

        $this->primary_keys[$table_name] = $field_name;
    }

    protected function relation_n_n_queries($select)
    {
        $this_table_primary_key = $this->get_primary_key();
        foreach($this->relation_n_n as $relation_n_n)
        {
            list($field_name, $relation_table, $selection_table, $primary_key_alias_to_this_table,
                        $primary_key_alias_to_selection_table, $title_field_selection_table, $priority_field_relation_table) = array_values((array)$relation_n_n);

            $primary_key_selection_table = $this->get_primary_key($selection_table);

            $field = "";
            $use_template = strpos($title_field_selection_table,'{') !== false;
            $field_name_hash = $this->_unique_field_name($title_field_selection_table);
            if($use_template)
            {
                $title_field_selection_table = str_replace(" ", "&nbsp;", $title_field_selection_table);
                $field .= "CONCAT('".str_replace(array('{','}'),array("',COALESCE(",", ''),'"),str_replace("'","\\'",$title_field_selection_table))."')";
            }
            else
            {
                $field .= "$selection_table.$title_field_selection_table";
            }

            //Sorry Codeigniter but you cannot help me with the subquery!
            $select .= ", (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT $field) FROM $selection_table "
                ."LEFT JOIN $relation_table ON $relation_table.$primary_key_alias_to_selection_table = $selection_table.$primary_key_selection_table "
                ."WHERE $relation_table.$primary_key_alias_to_this_table = `{$this->table_name}`.$this_table_primary_key GROUP BY $relation_table.$primary_key_alias_to_this_table) AS $field_name";
        }

        return $select;
    }

    function order_by($order_by , $direction)
    {
        $this->db->order_by( $order_by , $direction );
    }

    function where($key, $value = NULL, $escape = TRUE)
    {
        $this->db->where( $key, $value, $escape);
    }

    function or_where($key, $value = NULL, $escape = TRUE)
    {
        $this->db->or_where( $key, $value, $escape);
    }

    function having($key, $value = NULL, $escape = TRUE)
    {
        $this->db->having( $key, $value, $escape);
    }

    function or_having($key, $value = NULL, $escape = TRUE)
    {
        $this->db->or_having( $key, $value, $escape);
    }

    function like($field, $match = '', $side = 'both')
    {
        $this->db->like($field, $match, $side);
    }

    function or_like($field, $match = '', $side = 'both')
    {
        $this->db->or_like($field, $match, $side);
    }

    function limit($value, $offset = '')
    {
        $this->db->limit( $value , $offset );
    }

    function get_total_results()
    {
        //set_relation_n_n special queries. We prefer sub queries from a simple join for the relation_n_n as it is faster and more stable on big tables.
        if(!empty($this->relation_n_n))
        {
            $select = "{$this->table_name}.*";
            $select = $this->relation_n_n_queries($select);

            $this->db->select($select,false);
        }

        return $this->db->get($this->table_name)->num_rows();
    }

    function set_basic_table($table_name = null)
    {
        if( !($this->db->table_exists($table_name)) )
            return false;

        $this->table_name = $table_name;

        return true;
    }

    function get_edit_values($primary_key_value)
    {
        $primary_key_field = $this->get_primary_key();
        $this->db->where($primary_key_field,$primary_key_value);
        $result = $this->db->get($this->table_name)->row();
        return $result;
    }

    function join_relation($field_name , $related_table , $related_field_title)
    {
        $related_primary_key = $this->get_primary_key($related_table);

        if($related_primary_key !== false)
        {
            $unique_name = $this->_unique_join_name($field_name);
            $this->db->join( $related_table.' as '.$unique_name , "$unique_name.$related_primary_key = {$this->table_name}.$field_name",'left');

            $this->relation[$field_name] = array($field_name , $related_table , $related_field_title);

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    function set_relation_n_n_field($field_info)
    {
        $this->relation_n_n[$field_info->field_name] = $field_info;
    }

    protected function _unique_join_name($field_name)
    {
        return 'j'.substr(md5($field_name),0,8); //This j is because is better for a string to begin with a letter and not with a number
    }

    protected function _unique_field_name($field_name)
    {
        return 's'.substr(md5($field_name),0,8); //This s is because is better for a string to begin with a letter and not with a number
    }

    function get_relation_array($field_name , $related_table , $related_field_title, $where_clause, $order_by, $limit = null, $search_like = null)
    {
        $relation_array = array();
        $field_name_hash = $this->_unique_field_name($field_name);

        $related_primary_key = $this->get_primary_key($related_table);

        $select = "$related_table.$related_primary_key, ";

        if(strstr($related_field_title,'{'))
        {
            $related_field_title = str_replace(" ", "&nbsp;", $related_field_title);
            $select .= "CONCAT('".str_replace(array('{','}'),array("',COALESCE(",", ''),'"),str_replace("'","\\'",$related_field_title))."') as $field_name_hash";
        }
        else
        {
            $select .= "$related_table.$related_field_title as $field_name_hash";
        }

        $this->db->select($select,false);
        if($where_clause !== null)
            $this->db->where($where_clause);

        if($where_clause !== null)
            $this->db->where($where_clause);

        if($limit !== null)
            $this->db->limit($limit);

        if($search_like !== null)
            $this->db->having("$field_name_hash LIKE '%".$this->db->escape_like_str($search_like)."%'");

        $order_by !== null
            ? $this->db->order_by($order_by)
            : $this->db->order_by($field_name_hash);

        $results = $this->db->get($related_table)->result();

        foreach($results as $row)
        {
            $relation_array[$row->$related_primary_key] = $row->$field_name_hash;
        }

        return $relation_array;
    }

    function get_ajax_relation_array($search, $field_name , $related_table , $related_field_title, $where_clause, $order_by)
    {
        return $this->get_relation_array($field_name , $related_table , $related_field_title, $where_clause, $order_by, 10 , $search);
    }

    function get_relation_total_rows($field_name , $related_table , $related_field_title, $where_clause)
    {
        if($where_clause !== null)
            $this->db->where($where_clause);

        return $this->db->count_all_results($related_table);
    }

    function get_relation_n_n_selection_array($primary_key_value, $field_info)
    {
        $select = "";
        $related_field_title = $field_info->title_field_selection_table;
        $use_template = strpos($related_field_title,'{') !== false;;
        $field_name_hash = $this->_unique_field_name($related_field_title);
        if($use_template)
        {
            $related_field_title = str_replace(" ", "&nbsp;", $related_field_title);
            $select .= "CONCAT('".str_replace(array('{','}'),array("',COALESCE(",", ''),'"),str_replace("'","\\'",$related_field_title))."') as $field_name_hash";
        }
        else
        {
            $select .= "$related_field_title as $field_name_hash";
        }
        $this->db->select('*, '.$select,false);

        $selection_primary_key = $this->get_primary_key($field_info->selection_table);

        if(empty($field_info->priority_field_relation_table))
        {
            if(!$use_template){
                $this->db->order_by("{$field_info->selection_table}.{$field_info->title_field_selection_table}");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $this->db->order_by("{$field_info->relation_table}.{$field_info->priority_field_relation_table}");
        }
        $this->db->where($field_info->primary_key_alias_to_this_table, $primary_key_value);
        $this->db->join(
                $field_info->selection_table,
                "{$field_info->relation_table}.{$field_info->primary_key_alias_to_selection_table} = {$field_info->selection_table}.{$selection_primary_key}"
            );
        $results = $this->db->get($field_info->relation_table)->result();

        $results_array = array();
        foreach($results as $row)
        {
            $results_array[$row->{$field_info->primary_key_alias_to_selection_table}] = $row->{$field_name_hash};
        }

        return $results_array;
    }

    function get_relation_n_n_unselected_array($field_info, $selected_values)
    {
        $use_where_clause = !empty($field_info->where_clause);

        $select = "";
        $related_field_title = $field_info->title_field_selection_table;
        $use_template = strpos($related_field_title,'{') !== false;
        $field_name_hash = $this->_unique_field_name($related_field_title);

        if($use_template)
        {
            $related_field_title = str_replace(" ", "&nbsp;", $related_field_title);
            $select .= "CONCAT('".str_replace(array('{','}'),array("',COALESCE(",", ''),'"),str_replace("'","\\'",$related_field_title))."') as $field_name_hash";
        }
        else
        {
            $select .= "$related_field_title as $field_name_hash";
        }
        $this->db->select('*, '.$select,false);

        if($use_where_clause){
            $this->db->where($field_info->where_clause);
        }

        $selection_primary_key = $this->get_primary_key($field_info->selection_table);
        if(!$use_template)
            $this->db->order_by("{$field_info->selection_table}.{$field_info->title_field_selection_table}");
        $results = $this->db->get($field_info->selection_table)->result();

        $results_array = array();
        foreach($results as $row)
        {
            if(!isset($selected_values[$row->$selection_primary_key]))
                $results_array[$row->$selection_primary_key] = $row->{$field_name_hash};
        }

        return $results_array;
    }

    function db_relation_n_n_update($field_info, $post_data ,$main_primary_key)
    {
        $this->db->where($field_info->primary_key_alias_to_this_table, $main_primary_key);
        if(!empty($post_data))
            $this->db->where_not_in($field_info->primary_key_alias_to_selection_table , $post_data);
        $this->db->delete($field_info->relation_table);

        $counter = 0;
        if(!empty($post_data))
        {
            foreach($post_data as $primary_key_value)
            {
                $where_array = array(
                    $field_info->primary_key_alias_to_this_table => $main_primary_key,
                    $field_info->primary_key_alias_to_selection_table => $primary_key_value,
                );

                $this->db->where($where_array);
                $count = $this->db->from($field_info->relation_table)->count_all_results();

                if($count == 0)
                {
                    if(!empty($field_info->priority_field_relation_table))
                        $where_array[$field_info->priority_field_relation_table] = $counter;

                    $this->db->insert($field_info->relation_table, $where_array);

                }elseif($count >= 1 && !empty($field_info->priority_field_relation_table))
                {
                    $this->db->update( $field_info->relation_table, array($field_info->priority_field_relation_table => $counter) , $where_array);
                }

                $counter++;
            }
        }
    }

    function db_relation_n_n_delete($field_info, $main_primary_key)
    {
        $this->db->where($field_info->primary_key_alias_to_this_table, $main_primary_key);
        $this->db->delete($field_info->relation_table);
    }

    function get_field_types_basic_table()
    {
        $db_field_types = array();
        foreach($this->db->field_data($this->table_name) as $db_field_type)
        {

            $type = explode("(",$db_field_type->type);
            $db_type = $type[0];

            if(isset($type[1]))
            {
                if(substr($type[1],-1) == ')')
                {
                    $length = substr($type[1],0,-1);
                }
                else
                {
                    list($length) = explode(" ",$type[1]);
                    $length = substr($length,0,-1);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $length = '';
            }
            $db_field_types[$db_field_type->name]['db_max_length'] = $length;
            $db_field_types[$db_field_type->name]['db_type'] = $db_type;
            $db_field_types[$db_field_type->name]['db_null'] = $db_field_type->default == 'null' ? true : false;
            }

        $results = $this->db->field_data($this->table_name);
        foreach($results as $num => $row)
        {
            $row = (array)$row;
            $results[$num] = (object)( array_merge($row, $db_field_types[$row['name']])  );
        }

        return $results;
    }

    function get_field_types($table_name)
    {
        $results = $this->db->field_data($table_name);

        return $results;
    }

    function db_update($post_array, $primary_key_value)
    {
        $primary_key_field = $this->get_primary_key();
        return $this->db->update($this->table_name,$post_array, array( $primary_key_field => $primary_key_value));
    }

    function db_insert($post_array)
    {
        $insert = $this->db->insert($this->table_name,$post_array);
        if($insert)
        {
            return $this->db->insert_id();
        }
        return false;
    }

    function db_delete($primary_key_value)
    {
        $primary_key_field = $this->get_primary_key();

        if($primary_key_field === false)
            return false;

        $this->db->delete($this->table_name,array( $primary_key_field => $primary_key_value));
        if( $this->db->affected_rows() != 1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    function db_file_delete($field_name, $filename)
    {
        if( $this->db->update($this->table_name,array($field_name => ''),array($field_name => $filename)) )
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function field_exists($field,$table_name = null)
    {
        if(empty($table_name))
        {
            $table_name = $this->table_name;
        }
        return $this->db->field_exists($field,$table_name);
    }

    function get_primary_key($table_name = null)
    {
        if($table_name == null)
        {
            if(isset($this->primary_keys[$this->table_name]))
            {
                return $this->primary_keys[$this->table_name];
            }

            if(empty($this->primary_key))
            {
                $fields = $this->get_field_types_basic_table();

                foreach($fields as $field)
                {
                    if($field->primary_key == 1)
                    {
                        return $field->name;
                    }
                }

                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return $this->primary_key;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(isset($this->primary_keys[$table_name]))
            {
                return $this->primary_keys[$table_name];
            }

            $fields = $this->get_field_types($table_name);

            foreach($fields as $field)
            {
                if($field->primary_key == 1)
                {
                    return $field->name;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

    }

    function escape_str($value)
    {
        return $this->db->escape_str($value);
    }

}
```

Here is the connection :

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,11433';
$db['default']['username'] = 'xxxx'; // usuario por defecto del SQL
$db['default']['password'] = 'xxxx'; //Contaseña del usuario
$db['default']['database'] = 'xxxx'; // Base de datos que cree
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'sqlsrv';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Here is the controller: (need to specify primary key)

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
 /* Heredamos de la clase CI_Controller */
class Personas extends CI_Controller {

  function __construct()
  {

    parent::__construct();

    /* Cargamos la base de datos */
    $this->load->database();

    /* Cargamos la libreria*/
    $this->load->library('grocery_crud');

    /* Añadimos el helper al controlador */
    $this->load->helper('url');
  }

  function index()
  {
    /*
     * Mandamos todo lo que llegue a la funcion
     * administracion().
     **/
    redirect('personas/administracion');
  }

  /*
   *
   **/
  function administracion()
  {
    try{

    /* Creamos el objeto */
    $crud = new grocery_CRUD();

    /* Seleccionamos el tema */
    $crud->set_theme('flexigrid');

    /* Seleccionmos el nombre de la tabla de nuestra base de datos*/
    $crud->set_table('PERSONA_TEST');

    /* Le asignamos un nombre */
    $crud->set_subject('personas');

    /* Asignamos el idioma español */
    $crud->set_language('spanish');

    /* Aqui le decimos a grocery que estos campos son obligatorios */
    $crud->required_fields(
      'ID',
      'NOMBRE',
      'APELLIDO'
    );

    /* Aqui le indicamos que campos deseamos mostrar */
    $crud->columns(
     'ID',
      'NOMBRE',
      'APELLIDO'
    );

    $crud->set_primary_key('ID','PERSONA_TEST');

    /* Generamos la tabla */
    $output = $crud->render();

    /* La cargamos en la vista situada en
    /applications/views/productos/administracion.php */
    $this->load->view('personas/administracion', $output);

    }catch(Exception $e){
      /* Si algo sale mal cachamos el error y lo mostramos */
      show_error($e->getMessage().' --- '.$e->getTraceAsString());
    }
  }
}
```

And the view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Administracion Personas</title>
<?php
foreach($css_files as $file): ?>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $file; ?>" />
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php foreach($js_files as $file): ?>
<script src="<?php echo $file; ?>"></script>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<style type='text/css'>
body
{
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 14px;
}
a {
color: blue;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 14px;
}
a:hover
{
text-decoration: underline;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Administración de Personas</h1>
<div>
<?php echo $output; ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also i used this tutorial for the crud:

http://sourcezilla.com/articulos/programacion/como-realizar-un-crud-sencillo-en-php-y-codeigniter-desde-cero.html

Hope helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think ms sql server supports "show column" statement.  You need change your code , or db server, or the model configuration.

Comment: Yes that's the problem, but the code i need to change is the framework itself. Maybe someone have do that.